# Crawling external database with security trimming

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, crawling, security-trimming, external-data

We have a legacy records management system that we want to index in SharePoint 2013. We just want to index it and leave the documents where they are.

The records management system of course has a ACL applied to all documents, search results are therefore security trimmed.

I need to account for those when crawling the content from SharePoint.

We only use groups for applying permissions in both systems.
For SharePoint we use AD security groups
The records management system has its own ACL implementation however the group names used are identical

Do you have any resource you could point me that would help me create such a component?

Answer (score 0):

what you need, You have to give the read permission to **default content access account** on the Legacy system. This way it will index the data.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178512(v=office.15).aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee792876(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, how to I tell SharePoint to map the ACL of the legacy system to SharePoint?